# How to communicated between sibling in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, parent-child

So I have 3 tabs `HEX` , `RGB`, and `HSL` as `StatefulWidget`.

I have these 3 tabs in a `Row` in a `StatelessWidget`.

By default, `HEX` is selected, which I achieved successfully by initialising `initState()`. What I want to achieve now is that if I tap on any tab, the other two have to automatically go to a deselected state.

I used `GestureDetector` but it only changes the state of the tab I tapped on. I toggled the styles of all 3 tabs in the `setState()` function, but I guess the changes don't take place as the other 2 tabs are not built again, only the tab I tapped on is built again. By built I mean `createState()`.

I am a beginner in Flutter, and I have spent a whole day finding solutions to this but to no avail.

I tried rebuilding the parent `Row` but I am not able to do so. I am trying to find a method by which I can rebuild widgets by `key`.

Any solution?

EDIT: The code for that section ->

```dart
key arrayKey = GlobalKey();

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//++++++++++++++++++++CHIPS++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

class chipMaker extends StatefulWidget {

  chipMaker({required this.label}) : key = ObjectKey(label), chipSelect = false;
  final String label;
  final Key key;
  bool chipSelect;

  @override
  _chipState createState() => _chipState();
}

class _chipState extends State<chipMaker> {

  chipMaker get chip => super.widget;
  
  //need to add setState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        //function
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 2),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: defaultColor,
            width: 2,
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
          color: chip.chipSelect ? defaultColor : Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Text(
          chip.label,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 10,
            height: 1.2,
            color: chip.chipSelect ? Colors.white : defaultColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//++++++++++++++++++++ARRAY++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

class chipArray extends StatelessWidget {

  chipArray({Key? arrayKey,}) : super(key: arrayKey);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Row(
      children: [
        chipMaker(label: 'HEX',),
        chipMaker(label: 'RGB',),
        chipMaker(label: 'HSL',),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check this will be of any help or not https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

Comment: The article linked above is a very good read for this. I think in your example you need to make your ChipArray (please name class with uppercase letter) statefull - this is the one that will need to coordinate your chips and maintain which one is selected. At the same time your ChipMaker should be stateless - even now you are not keeping any state - all your variables are final; and there is nothing in the state object apart from build method and getter for widget.